# PowerShell скопировать name в SamAccountName

Tags: powershell

Доброе время суток,
Задача: у меня есть пользователи 1000шт. у которых Name: Dima | SamAccountName: $UHAFLK-65463
Как через PowerShell скопировать Name в SamAccountName ?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала занесите ваших пользователей в массив и ищите пользователей по SamAccountName в качестве identity.

Используйте командлет Set-ADUser, чтобы установить в качестве значения SamAccountName имя name.
Само собой, для примера ниже объект $user должен иметь два свойства -SamAccountName и name заранее, то есть вы должны подготовить массив.

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -SamAccountName $user.name
}
```

Параметр -Identity принимает следующие значения:

- distinguished name
- GUID (objectGUID)
- security identifier (objectSid)
- SAM account name (sAMAccountName)